# How to construct a condition to choose appropriate function in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have two apps and want them to run one function in view.py and render in template. The only difference is that each app uses different models. For example, my first app uses function called like_post_fin:

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post_Fin, id=request.POST.get('id'))
```

and my second app uses function called like_post:

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('id'))
```

other part of code is same for each function. 
In my first app template I will use to call function:

```
<form action="{% url 'like_post_fin' %}" method="post">
```

In my second app template I will use:

```
<form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="post">
```

other part of html code is same for both template.

When I run codes separately everything works perfect. But I want to have just one function and template for both apps which should use condition in view function or template.

I tried to use condition in app's template by using following code

```
{% if title == 'my app title' %}
<form action="{% url 'like_post_fin' %}" method="post">
{% else %}
<form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="post">
{% endif %}
```

But it did not work. Template titles are given using following code:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['title'] = 'my app title'
```

In my base html

```
{% if title %}
   <title>web - {{ title }}</title>
{% else %}
    <title> web </title>
{% endif %}
```

So, how to make condition in template or view file function

Comment: Have you considered template inheritance instead of the if/else?

Comment: @tepeholm Make sure that you `return context` from `get_context_data`

Comment: yes I did not miss return context

Comment: I think  template inheritance is not the case, since I have javascript and ajax codes related to the name of the function. I dont want produce cumbersome code which repeat itself except one line in code.